# Showing an error of Undefined index: password

Tags: php, laravel

I my session controller i code for the verify email ,login and changepassword but getting an error

> ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 116:
>   Undefined index: password.

and getting the error from line code

```
if (!Auth::attempt($credentials_verifiy))
```

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use Response;
//----models--------
use App\Site;
use App\Jobs;


use Auth;
use DB;
use Validator;
use Redirect;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
class SessionController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        return Redirect::to('login')->with('alert-success', 'test awrnning message.');
    }
    public function store()
    {
             $input = Request::only('username', 'email', 'password');
             $credentials = [
                 'username' => Request::get('username'),
                 'password' => Request::get('password')
             ];

            if (!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            {
                return Redirect::back()->with('alert-danger', 'Username or password do not match.');
            }
            else
            {
                $credentials_verifiy = [
                    'verified_email' => '1'
                ];
                if (!Auth::attempt($credentials_verifiy))
                {
                    return Redirect::back()->with('alert-danger', 'Please verify your email.');
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Auth::user()->last_login_at=='' || Auth::user()->last_login_at==null)
                    {
                        return redirect('/change_password');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return redirect('/tests');
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to skip this Exception you can use this line of code

```
array_get('password', $input);
```

if the array `$input` has no index `password` it will not throw an Exception, it will return null, you can make it returns what you want : `array_get('password', $input, ' ');`

Comment: can you please explain how to use in $credentials_verifiy = [
                    'verified_email' => '1'
                ];
                if (!Auth::attempt($credentials_verifiy))
                {
                    return Redirect::back()->with('alert-danger', 'Please verify your email.');
                }

Comment: just replace with this : 
`$credentials = [
                 'username' => array_get('username', $input, ' '),
                 'password' => array_get('password', $input, ' ')
             ];`

Comment: how can icheck not null in credential.

Comment: how to 'last_login_at' field is not null with $credentials = [ 'username' => array_get('username', $input, ' '), 'password' => array_get('password', $input, ' ') ];

Comment: try to do this `if (!Auth::attempt(array_merge($credentials_verifiy, $credentials))`

Answer (score 1):

`$credentials` array in `Auth::attempt($credentials)` should contain value with `password` key, that's why you're getting the error. It's [hardcoded in validateCredentials()](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/5.3/EloquentUserProvider.php#L116) method which `Auth::attempt()` is using:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

Comment: but in  this line if (!Auth::attempt($credentials_verifiy))    i just need to check the credential related to verified_email field only.